# Adding jQuery function from Serverside

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'd like to know how I could add a jQuery function from the server side. I am doing this for attaching to the onClick event on rad

```
rbtn_Value.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:onGlobalDiscountTypeChange(this)");
```

that was not the jQuery function, now i need to add the onFocusOut function of jQuery mentioned here http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

I'd like to know how I could do that from server like I am doing for OnClick event?

Comment: Why are you manually binding the click event to a jQuery function? Just write it on the client side.

Comment: i need to as i have many text boxes and i want to add those all from sever side

Answer (score 1):

Before rendering the page you add this script into any server_side event

```
 string script="$(document).ready(function(){$('#"+rbtn_Value.ClientID+"')
   .focusout(function(){functionToExecute})";

 ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"discountFocus",script,true);
```

Comment: its giving wrror Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, GetType(), "onclick", "onGlobalDiscountTypeChange(this); return false;", true);
```

Comment: i dont want onclick, bt jQuery onFacusOut